# Mono is using mscorlib.dll 2.0 instead of 4.0 in Ubuntu with ASP.NET Web application

Tags: asp.net, linux, mono, mscorlib

I'm new here.

I have searched this site for answers and I found a workaround, but I'd still like get the original problem solved. I have set the target framework to `Mono/.NET 4.0` and I am using `Mysql.Data.dll`. It compiles fine, but when I am trying to run it on xsp2 web server on my laptop, I run into errors:

> Missing method .ctor in assembly
>   /tmp/kari-temp-aspnet-0/eaee30a1/assembly/shadow/04e2c4cc/18848ad4_1c664e18_00000001/MySql.Data.dll,
>   type System.Security.SecurityRulesAttribute
>   Can't find custom attr
>   constructor image:
>   /tmp/kari-temp-aspnet-0/eaee30a1/assembly/shadow/04e2c4cc/18848ad4_1c664e18_00000001/MySql.Data.dll
>   mtoken: 0x0a00002a
>   Missing method
>   System.Threading.Monitor::Enter(object,bool&) in assembly
>   /usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll, referenced in assembly
>   /tmp/kari-temp-aspnet-0/eaee30a1/assembly/shadow/04e2c4cc/18848ad4_1c664e18_00000001/MySql.Data.dll

Here you can see that it is using `.../2.0/mscorlib.dll`. I have tried to create a new project, like this thread suggests [Mono take mscorlib.dll 2.0 instead of 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878948/mono-take-mscorlib-dll-2-0-instead-of-4-0) but it still does the same. If I set the target framework to `Mono/.NET 2.0`, I run into some other errors.

For the workaround, I renamed `mscorlib.dll` in 2.0 and then made a symbolic link to the same file in 4.0 directory as some post here suggested and it works, but I'm not happy with that.

Is there a way to manually edit a project configuration file to select a 4.0 target instead of 2.0? Should this be reported as a bug to MonoDevelop? I am using MonoDevelop 2.8.6.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how xsp works:

```
xsp2 => mscorlib.dll 2.0  
xsp4 => mscorlib.dll 4.0
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I didn't have the xsp4 in my monodevelop package for some reason so I had to install it separately. I removed the workaround and the project is running ok.