# Testing Windows DOTNET Service on Linux using mono-service

Tags: c#, linux, .net-4.0, mono, mono-service

I'm trying to run a Windows .NET-4.0 service on Linux using mono-service. It's not compiled with mono or anything. I'm not 100% it's doable but I thought I could try (binary compatible etc, seems [doable](http://mattdeboard.net/2012/10/19/how-to-run-windows-service-as-linux-daemon/)?). Correct me if I'm wrong.

I'm getting errors that it can't find some dlls. They are in the system but it's not finding them. Here's one.

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep Posix
    libMonoPosixHelper.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libMonoPosixHelper.so
```

I try with adding the path etc but no change.

```
$ MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono-service MyService.exe --debug > output.log
```

or

```
$ MONO_PATH=/usr/lib MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono-service MyService.exe --debug > output.log
```

or LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which was empty, so I tried

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib
```

Always like this in the output:

```
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/libMonoPosixHelper.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/libMonoPosixHelper.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/libMonoPosixHelper.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/libMonoPosixHelper.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so'.
```

So it's not finding it in the base path, just looking in the GAC. Why isn't it looking there? It should look in MONO_PATH before GAC? Am I missing something?

Tested on two VMs: Ubuntu 13.04 and a clean live Mint 14.

### edit, add info 9/10:

Ok, Ubuntu had version 2.10 or something, I tried with the latest source

```
$ sudo ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.1 (tarball Tue Sep 10 12:25:30 CEST 2013)
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib MONO_LOG_LEVEL=info mono-service MyService.exe --debug > output.log
```

output.log:

```
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Image addref mscorlib[0xdb0130] -> /usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll[0xdaf370]: 2
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: AOT loaded AOT Module for /usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll.

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/mscorlib/mscorlib.config'.
Mono: GC_MAJOR: (mature allocation failure) pause 0.16ms, total 0.16ms, bridge 0.00 major 96K/32K los 0K/0K
Mono: Assembly mscorlib[0xdb0130] added to domain mono-service.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/home/ejpb/.mono/config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe'.
Mono: Image addref mono-service[0xdf0660] -> /usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe[0xdae210]: 3
Mono: Assembly mono-service[0xdf0660] added to domain mono-service.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe.so: /usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/mono-service/mono-service.config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe'.
Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe.so: /usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Ref addref mono-service[0xdf0660] -> mscorlib[0xdb0130]: 2
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe.config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/Mono.Posix.dll'.
Mono: Image addref Mono.Posix[0xe0bba0] -> /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll[0xe0ae00]: 2
Mono: Assembly Mono.Posix[0xe0bba0] added to domain mono-service.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll.so: /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/Mono.Posix.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/Mono.Posix/Mono.Posix.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref mono-service[0xdf0660] -> Mono.Posix[0xe0bba0]: 2
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Mono.Posix[0xe0bba0] -> mscorlib[0xdb0130]: 3
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'libc.so.6'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/libc.so.6': '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/libc.so.6.so': '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/libc.so.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loaded library 'libc.so.6'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libc.so.6' ('libc.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'chdir'.
Mono: Probing 'chdir'.
Mono: Found as 'chdir'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/libMonoPosixHelper.so': '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/libMonoPosixHelper.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/libMonoPosixHelper.so': '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/libMonoPosixHelper.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loaded library 'libMonoPosixHelper.so'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_open_mode'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_open_mode'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_open_mode'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_lockf'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_lockf'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_lockf'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libc.so.6' ('libc.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'getpid'.
Mono: Probing 'getpid'.
Mono: Found as 'getpid'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_write'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_write'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_write'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_get_at_fdcwd'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_get_at_fdcwd'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_get_at_fdcwd'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_L_ctermid'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_L_ctermid'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_L_ctermid'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_L_cuserid'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_L_cuserid'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_L_cuserid'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_get_utime_now'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_get_utime_now'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_get_utime_now'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_get_utime_omit'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_get_utime_omit'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_get_utime_omit'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libc.so.6' ('libc.so.6').
Mono: Searching for 'free'.
Mono: Probing 'free'.
Mono: Found as 'free'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_malloc'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_malloc'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_malloc'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_SIG_DFL'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_SIG_DFL'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_SIG_DFL'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_SIG_ERR'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_SIG_ERR'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_SIG_ERR'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_SIG_IGN'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_SIG_IGN'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_SIG_IGN'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib__IOFBF'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib__IOFBF'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib__IOFBF'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib__IOLBF'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib__IOLBF'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib__IOLBF'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib__IONBF'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib__IONBF'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib__IONBF'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_BUFSIZ'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_BUFSIZ'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_BUFSIZ'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_EOF'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_EOF'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_EOF'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_FOPEN_MAX'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_FOPEN_MAX'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_FOPEN_MAX'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_FILENAME_MAX'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_FILENAME_MAX'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_FILENAME_MAX'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_L_tmpnam'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_L_tmpnam'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_L_tmpnam'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_stderr'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_stderr'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_stderr'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_stdin'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_stdin'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_stdin'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_stdout'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_stdout'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_stdout'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_TMP_MAX'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_TMP_MAX'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_TMP_MAX'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_EXIT_FAILURE'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_EXIT_FAILURE'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_EXIT_FAILURE'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_EXIT_SUCCESS'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_EXIT_SUCCESS'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_EXIT_SUCCESS'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_MB_CUR_MAX'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_MB_CUR_MAX'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_MB_CUR_MAX'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_RAND_MAX'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_RAND_MAX'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_RAND_MAX'.
Mono: Assembly mscorlib[0xdb0130] added to domain MyService.exe, ref_count=4
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/home/ejpb/mono-3.2.1/MyService.exe.config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll'.
Mono: Image addref Mono.Security[0xf159c0] -> /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll[0xf296f0]: 2
Mono: Assembly Mono.Security[0xf159c0] added to domain MyService.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll.so: /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Mono.Security[0xf159c0] -> mscorlib[0xdb0130]: 5
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/Mono.Security.dll'.
Mono: Unloading image /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll [0x1003f10].
Mono: Assembly Mono.Security[0xf159c0] added to domain mono-service.exe, ref_count=2
Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll.so: /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/mono-service/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/mono-service.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/mono-service.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/Facades/mono-service.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/mono-service/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/mono-service.exe'.
Mono: Image addref mono-service[0x109a0b0] -> /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/mono-service/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/mono-service.exe[0x106e200]: 2
Mono: Assembly mono-service[0x109a0b0] added to domain MyService.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/mono-service/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/mono-service.exe.so: /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/mono-service/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/mono-service.exe.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/mono-service/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/mono-service.exe'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/mono-service/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/mono-service.exe.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/mono-service/mono-service.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref mono-service[0x109a0b0] -> mscorlib[0xdb0130]: 6
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceProcess/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.ServiceProcess.dll'.
Mono: Image addref System.ServiceProcess[0x10bf5f0] -> /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceProcess/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.ServiceProcess.dll[0x10be7a0]: 2
Mono: Assembly System.ServiceProcess[0x10bf5f0] added to domain MyService.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceProcess/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.ServiceProcess.dll.so: /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceProcess/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.ServiceProcess.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceProcess/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.ServiceProcess.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceProcess/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.ServiceProcess.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.ServiceProcess/System.ServiceProcess.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref mono-service[0x109a0b0] -> System.ServiceProcess[0x10bf5f0]: 2
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll'.
Mono: Image addref System[0x10c0fc0] -> /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll[0x10c0290]: 2
Mono: Assembly System[0x10c0fc0] added to domain MyService.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll.so: /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System/System.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.ServiceProcess[0x10bf5f0] -> System[0x10c0fc0]: 2
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System[0x10c0fc0] -> mscorlib[0xdb0130]: 7
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.ServiceProcess[0x10bf5f0] -> mscorlib[0xdb0130]: 8
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: 'MyService.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Mono.Posix[0xe0bba0] added to domain MyService.exe, ref_count=3
Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll.so: /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Ref addref mono-service[0x109a0b0] -> Mono.Posix[0xe0bba0]: 4
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_syslog'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_syslog'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Syscall_syslog'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_FromSyslogLevel'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_FromSyslogLevel'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_FromSyslogLevel'.
Mono: GC_MAJOR: (user request) pause 1.18ms, total 1.20ms, bridge 0.00 major 704K/272K los 50K/120K
Mono: Unloading domain mono-service.exe[0xdaafb0], assembly __MetadataTypes[0x1025240], ref_count=1
Mono: Unloading assembly __MetadataTypes [0x1025240].
Mono: Unloading image __MetadataTypes [0x1003fc0].
Mono: Unloading image __MetadataTypes [0x102dba0].
Mono: Unloading domain mono-service.exe[0xdaafb0], assembly mscorlib[0xdb0130], ref_count=8
Mono: Unloading domain mono-service.exe[0xdaafb0], assembly mono-service[0xdf0660], ref_count=1
Mono: Unloading assembly mono-service [0xdf0660].
Mono: Unloading domain mono-service.exe[0xdaafb0], assembly Mono.Posix[0xe0bba0], ref_count=4
Mono: Unloading domain mono-service.exe[0xdaafb0], assembly Mono.Security[0xf159c0], ref_count=2
Mono: Unloading image /usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe [0xdae210].
Mono: Assembly image '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceProcess/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.ServiceProcess.dll' still loaded at shutdown.
Mono: Assembly image '/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll' still loaded at shutdown.
Mono: Assembly image '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll' still loaded at shutdown.
Mono: Assembly image '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll' still loaded at shutdown.
Mono: Assembly image '/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll' still loaded at shutdown.
Mono: Assembly image '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll' still loaded at shutdown.
Mono: Assembly image '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/mono-service/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/mono-service.exe' still loaded at shutdown.
Mono: Assembly image '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll' still loaded at shutdown.
Mono: Assembly image '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll' still loaded at shutdown.
Mono: Assembly image '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll' still loaded at shutdown.
Mono: Assembly image '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceProcess/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.ServiceProcess.dll' still loaded at shutdown.
```

Seems better, but it's still shutting down.

It finds libMonoPosixHelper
    `Mono: DllImport loaded library 'libMonoPosixHelper.so'.`
But fails on Posix:
    `Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll.so: /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
at the end of the log. Is that the main error that causes the shutdown?
Mono.Posix.dll is loaded earlier... I don't know if I'm missing something when reading the log.

### edit 9/30

OK, I tried with a CrunchBang vm, it has no Mono. Installed tarball with prefix /home/ejpb/mono (needed space, on /home partition).
Question: am I even doing it correctly? I have copied the exe and dll's from the installed directory on Windows. Can I use the msi file in Linux somehow (extract them from it)? Would that change anything?
I ran

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ejpb/mono/lib MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono-service -v /home/ejpb/MyService/MyService.exe --debug > out.log
```

and got in out.log:

```
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').  
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_RAND_MAX'.  
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_RAND_MAX'.  
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_RAND_MAX'.
```

etc, so that part seems ok now.

I also got quite a few "not found"
    Mono: AOT NOT FOUND: System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider:RngClose (intptr).
    Mono: AOT NOT FOUND: System.Threading.InternalThread:Thread_free_internal (intptr).
etc.

I tried MoMA - Mono 2.8 (4.0 Profile). Is that accurate for 3.2.3 also?
I got:

```
Assembly                  Version    Missing  Not Implemented  Todo  P/Invoke  
Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.dll   1.5.3.2578    0            4          11       0  
Apache.NMS.dll            1.5.0.2194    0            0           4       0  
log4net.dll               1.2.11.0      0            0           6       3  
MyServiceUtils.dll        1.0.0.0       1            0           0       0  
MyService.exe             1.0.0.0       0            0           1       0
```

Perhaps it's not possible to run this service? log4net has a few p/invokes etc.

Comment: seems like a broken mono installation, how did you install mono?

Comment: Standard apt-get of mono packages. mono, mono-gac, mono-4.0-service, mono-devel, mono-runtime, mono-utils. I tries adding some after each try. Could some of them cause this? Only mono-4.0-service should be needed basically, I guess.

Comment: it could be a bug in the library loading process, you should test with mono 3.2.3, and if it's still not fixed in this version, you may want to file it in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: Ok, I edited the question, see above.

Comment: why did you install in /usr/local and not /usr? if you still have the old 2.10 mono in /usr then you have screwed your mono installation, please google about "Mono parallel environment"

Comment: I followed a tutorial/howto blindly... I gave it another try on a clean system, added above.

Comment: you're still installing Mono 3.2.x in /usr/local, but you end up using Mono 2.x executable from /usr, don't do that, follow this: http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments

Comment: No, like I said it was a clean system, no Mono 2.x, and I used the source download of 3.2.3 and ran `./configure --prefix=/home/ejpb/mono && make && make install`, then added the prefix to the path. `which mono` gives `/home/ejpb/mono/bin/mono`. I looked at that page and didn't think it was needed on a clean system.

Comment: @ejpb Can you give us the entire output of that last run?  It makes sense to post it on its own instead of in the question: on https://gist.github.com/ or any similar site.

Comment: Ok, I ran it with the latest mono and added a summary and log [here](https://gist.github.com/ejpb/8470411).

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed mono using sudo apt-get install mono-complete, 
you might want to look at the mscorlib.

[Mono take mscorlib.dll 2.0 instead of 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878948/mono-take-mscorlib-dll-2-0-instead-of-4-0)

[Unable to run .net app with Mono - mscorlib.dll not found (version mismatch?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490155/unable-to-run-net-app-with-mono-mscorlib-dll-not-found-version-mismatch)

might be of use.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, probably, but no, I have used the tarball after the initial question. I have an summary and log of my latest try in a "hidden" comment above.